# Call a component's onChange method inside another one in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks, onclick

There is a Selector component of this form:

```
<Selector
  initialSelectedOption={data[0].type}
  onChange={(val) => changeValue(val.name)}
  options={valueOptions}
/>;
```

when the user selects a value from the dropdown, `onChange` is called and the value is updated in the selector.

I want to reset the value to the original one once the user has clicked cancel:

```
 <Button onClick={handleCancel} />
...

  const handleCancel = () => {
    changeValue(data[0].type);
  };
```

However, something is wrong here as it is not called.

Is it a way to call the `Selector`'s `onChange` method from `handleCancel`?

Comment: `However, something is wrong here as it is not called.` It certainly should be. Can you share more code from the component that demonstrates the problem more clearly?

Answer (score 0):

We need a bit more context to know for sure, but in general, you should define `onChange` in a parent component and pass it as a prop to both the selector component and the component that handles the cancel.